# pnpm & vue & vite monorepo - resolve import of alias path inside a workspace package

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vite, monorepo, pnpm

I'm building a monorepo of UI applications using shared components and style using pnpm, typescript, vue, and vite.

While trying to leverage pnpm's workspace ecosystem to ease the development experience and deployment, I'm struggling with using alias paths when importing a package into an app.

This is my folder structure:

```
    src/
    |
    |- apps/
    |   |- app1/
    |   |   |- env/
    |   |   |- node_modules/
    |   |   |- src/
    |   |   |   |- plugins/
    |   |   |   |   |- some-logic.ts
    |   |   |   |- styles/
    |   |   |   |   |- app.scss
    |   |   |   |- views/
    |   |   |   |   |- HomeView.vue
    |   |   |   ...
    |   |   |   |- App.vue
    |   |   |   |- main.ts
    |   |   |
    |   |   |- index.html
    |   |   |- package.json
    |   |   |- tsconfig.json
    |   |   |- vite.config.ts
    |
    |- packages/
    |   |- shared-ui/
    |   |   |- node_modules/
    |   |   |- src/
    |   |   |   |- components/
    |   |   |   |   |- Header.vue
    |   |   |   |- plugins/
    |   |   |   |   |- another-logic.ts
    |   |   |   |- styles/
    |   |   |   |   |- header.scss
    |   |   |- package.json
    |   |   |- tsconfig.json
    |
    |- node_modules/
    ...
    |- package.json
    |- pnpm-lock.yaml
    |- pnpm-workspace.yaml
    |- tsconfig.base.json
    ...
    |- package.json
    |- pnpm-lock.yaml
    |- pnpm-workspace.yaml
    |- tsconfig.base.json
```

My `HomeView.vue` in my application is importing the `Header.vue` component of my shared-ui package:

```js
    <script setup lang="ts">
    import stuff from '@/plugins/some-logic.ts'
    import Header from '@namespace/shared-ui/src/components/Header.vue';
    
    stuff();
    </script>
    
    <template>
        <div class="container">
            <Header />
        </div>
    </template>
    
    <style lang="scss">
    @import '@/styles/app.scss';
    </style>
```

As you can see above, `@/` acts as a path alias for the `src` folder of the application. This works as expected. The problem starts under the `Header` component:

```js
    <script setup lang="ts">
    import moreStuff from '@/plugins/another-logic.ts' // doesn't work
    
    
    moreStuff();
    </script>
    
    <template>
        <div class="header">
            ...
        </div>
    </template>
    
    <style lang="scss">
    // @import '@/styles/header.scss'; // doesn't work
    @import '../styles/header.scss'; // works
    </style>
```

My guess is since the entry point of vite is `src/apps/app1/`, and in the vite's config, I've created an alias of `@` to `src/`, it's trying to resolve the `@` of the package as well, and leads to wrong import as described below:

```bash
    import/no-unresolved    Unable to resolve path to module '@/plugins/another-logic.ts'
    import/no-unresolved    [vite] Internal server error: [sass] ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/namespace/apps/app1/src/styles/header.scss'
```

---

**root package.json**

```json
    {
      "name": "namespace",
      "private": true,
      "type": "module",
      "packageManager": "pnpm@8.6.9",
      "browserslist": [
        "> 1%",
        "last 2 versions",
        "not dead",
        "not ie <= 11"
      ],
      "devDependencies": {
        "@types/node": "~20.3.3",
        "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "~5.61.0",
        "@typescript-eslint/parser": "~5.61.0",
        "eslint": "~8.44.0",
        "eslint-config-prettier": "~8.8.0",
        "eslint-import-resolver-typescript": "~3.5.5",
        "eslint-plugin-import": "~2.27.5",
        "eslint-plugin-prettier": "~4.2.1",
        "eslint-plugin-vue": "~9.15.1",
        "prettier": "~2.8.8",
        "ts-node": "~10.9.1",
        "typescript": "~5.1.6",
        "vite": "~4.3.9",
        "vite-plugin-eslint": "~1.8.1",
        "vue-eslint-parser": "~9.3.1"
      }
    }
```

**pnpm-workspace.yaml**

```yaml
    packages:
      - 'apps/*'
      - 'packages/*'
```

**tsconfig.base.json**

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es6",
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "strict": true,
    "jsx": "preserve",
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "noEmit": false,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "useDefineForClassFields": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "lib": [
      "esnext",
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable",
      "scripthost"
    ]
  },
  "references": [
    {
      "path": "./packages/shared-ui"
    }
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "**/node_modules",
    "packages/**/dist"
  ]
}
```

**apps/app1/package.json**

```json
    {
      "name": "@namespace/app1",
      "private": true,
      "type": "module",
      "packageManager": "pnpm@8.6.9",
      "scripts": {
        "serve": "vite"
      },
      "dependencies": {
        "@namespace/shared-ui": "workspace:*",
        "@vee-validate/zod": "~4.10.8",
        "axios": "~1.4.0",
        "pinia": "~2.1.4",
        "vee-validate": "~4.10.8",
        "vite-plugin-vuetify": "~1.0.2",
        "vue": "~3.3.4",
        "vue-router": "~4.2.4",
        "vuetify": "~3.3.6",
        "zod": "~3.21.4"
      },
      "devDependencies": {
        "@vitejs/plugin-vue": "~4.2.3",
        "sass": "~1.64.1",
        "vite-tsconfig-paths": "~4.2.0"
      }
    }
```

**apps/app1/tsconfig.json**

```json
    {
      "extends": "../../tsconfig.base.json",
      "compilerOptions": {
        "baseUrl": "./",
        "outDir": "./dist/",
        "paths": {
          "@/*": [
            "src/*"
          ]
        },
        "typeRoots": [
          "./node_modules/@types",
          "./src/types"
        ]
      },
      "include": [
        "src/**/*.ts",
        "src/**/*.d.ts",
        "src/**/*.tsx",
        "src/**/*.vue",
        "vite.config.ts"
      ]
    }
```

**apps/app1/vite.config.ts**

```js
    import { type UserConfigExport, defineConfig } from 'vite';
    import eslint from 'vite-plugin-eslint';
    import vuetify from 'vite-plugin-vuetify';
    import tsconfigPaths from 'vite-tsconfig-paths';
    
    import vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue';
    
    export default defineConfig(({ mode }) => {
        const isDevelopment = mode === 'development';
        const config: UserConfigExport = {
            root: `${process.cwd()}/`,
            envDir: `${process.cwd()}/env/`,
            plugins: [tsconfigPaths(), eslint(), vue(), vuetify()],
            resolve: {
                alias: {
                    '@/': `${process.cwd()}/src/`,
                    vue: 'vue/dist/vue.esm-bundler.js'
                }
            }
        };
    
        if (isDevelopment) {
            config.server = {
                host: true,
                port: Number(process.env.PORT)
            };
        }
    
        return config;
    });
```

**packages/shared-ui/package.json**

```json
    {
      "name": "@namespace/shared-ui",
      "private": true,
      "type": "module",
      "packageManager": "pnpm@8.6.9",
      "dependencies": {
        "axios": "~1.4.0"
      },
      "devDependencies": {
        "@vee-validate/zod": "~4.10.8",
        "vee-validate": "~4.10.8",
        "vue": "~3.3.4",
        "vuetify": "~3.3.6",
        "zod": "~3.21.4"
      }
    }
```

**packages/shared-ui/tsconfig.json**

```json
    {
      "extends": "../../tsconfig.base.json",
      "compilerOptions": {
        "baseUrl": "./",
        "outDir": "./dist/",
        "paths": {
          "@/*": [
            "src/*"
          ]
        },
        "typeRoots": [
          "./node_modules/@types",
          "./src/types"
        ]
      },
      "include": [
        "src/**/*.ts",
        "src/**/*.d.ts",
        "src/**/*.tsx",
        "src/**/*.vue"
      ]
    }
```

Comment: I don't see `plugins` in the file tree

Comment: If it says `Unable to resolve path to module '@/plugins/another-logic.ts'` show where it is

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As described in the following URL, `vite` (and `rollup`) apparently do not support resolving aliases with an array but only a string. The solution, as of this moment, is to pick different aliases per app/package.

https://github.com/vercel/turbo/discussions/620#discussioncomment-2136195

Answer (score 0):

my case with nextJS where

````
```
# pnpm-workspace.yaml
packages:
  - app
  - packages/*
```
````

I replaced:

```
"@/*": ["src/*"] -> "@<package_name>/*": ["src/*"]

 and in /app/tsconfig.json added:
"@<package_name>/*": ["../packages/<package_name>/src/*"]
```

It should translate to a vue & vite monorepo.